# Strange problem with `longtabu`

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tabu, booktabs

I would like to share with you a quite simple example LaTeX is not able to compile.

I use the `longtabu` environment provided by `tabu` package. I am using commands from `booktabs` as recommended in the documentation of `tabu`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}



\begin{footnotesize}

\begin{longtabu} to 0.75\textwidth{cX[L]ll}
% We use commands from 'booktabs' package because it is recommended by 'tabu'.
%
\caption[Short caption for index.]{Long caption to be shown at the top of the first page of the table.\label{tab:label}}
\toprule
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\caption[]{(Cont.) Long caption to be shown at the top of the rest of the table.}
\toprule
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
% Now the regular content :
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

In the `.log` file I get this error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\toprule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\abovetopsep \global \@b...
l.88 \end{longtabu}

I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.88 \end{longtabu}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

and many other similar errors. And the compiler doesn't end. I have to force it to stop.

The problem could be related with `caption` sentences, because if I delete them, the example is compiled and a proper document is produced.

What am I missing? Maybe it's a silly question, but I am not able to understand what's happening, so I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have forgotten to terminate the caption with an end of line `\\`. `longtabu`is base on the code from [longtable](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) (see [the manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) page 1 second paragraph), so [the longtable-manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) is actually part of the documentation for `longtabu`. The need for `\\` in captions, is documented on page 11 in that manual.

A suggestion: If you add a line

```
\tabulinesep=3pt
```

before the table, you get nicer spacing. Try this one:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{footnotesize}

\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{longtabu} to 0.75\textwidth{cX[L]ll}
% We use commands from 'booktabs' package 
% because it is recommended by 'tabu'.
%
\caption[Short caption for index.]{Long caption to be %
shown at the top of the first page %
of the table.\label{tab:label}}\\ % **NB**
\toprule
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\caption[]{(Cont.) Long caption to be shown at %
the top of the rest of the table.}\\  % **NB**
\toprule
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
% Now the regular content :
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
$\Phi(z)$ &
Description wich is quite long, normally. &
$]0,1[$ &
This is a reference page.
\\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! So easy... But I didn't find proper examples at `longtable` or `tabu` documentation. Ups... Now I see... So *there was* a proper example...

Comment: No, but the `tabu`-manual say it use the `longtable` code, and then I _guessed_ that I had to read the `longtable`-manual.